# Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:6667 (waiting for controller)

Tags: relays, circuit, stream-isolation, python

I'm running some experiments using the stem library where I change circuit paths fairly frequently. Every so often, I get a stream detached event and a `Socks5Error: 'TTL Expired'` in my Python script, and at the same time I get something like `Jan 12 12:09:52.000 [notice] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:6667. Giving up. (waiting for controller)` in my Tor log.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be occurring, and how I could either prevent it or even recover from it? I tried catching the exception, waiting, and then getting a new controller (with `Controller.from_port`) but the attempt to get a new controller throws a `Socks5Error` as well. Once I restart the script though, everything works fine until the error occurs agin.

Even if the error can't be prevented, I'd like the script to be able to keep going on it's own.

Comment: A few places actually block IRC (port 6667). Try using a different port, if you can.

Comment: If it's listed in their "rejected" ports list in the directory then that shouldn't be it, because I'm only using Tor exit nodes that say they allow exiting to *:6667

Comment: That doesn't eliminate the possibility that you've hit a bad exit, one whose ISP blocks the port (and the exit node operator is unaware of this).

Comment: Maybe you can set `SafeLogging 0` in your `torrc`, get the failing IP and test it using another Tor client or by other means.